# How to enable auto-complete in Emacs Org-babel?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, org-mode, babeljs

I would like to enable `auto-complete` for Babel code blocks in `org-mode`:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq )                 <--- language-aware auto-completion here
#+end_src
```

What do I need to add to my `.emacs` file in order to configure `auto-complete` to do this?

Comment: You can use <kbd>C-c '</kbd> to [bring up a new window](http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html#Editing-source-code) with your source code and the corresponding major mode.

Comment: This is a good way too.

Comment: @Juancho I think you should post that (but elaborated) as an answer.

Comment: at least you can get tab to act as the native mode like this. `(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most robust (and entirely not `org-mode` specific) way to do this involves an `indirect buffer`. [Here's](http://demonastery.org/2013/04/emacs-narrow-to-region-indirect/) a blog post that explains indirect buffers in depth. Basically an indirect buffer mirrors the contents of a section of another buffer.

```lisp
(defun narrow-to-region-indirect (start end)
  "Restrict editing in this buffer to the current region, indirectly."
  (interactive "r")
  (deactivate-mark)
  (let ((buf (clone-indirect-buffer nil nil)))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (narrow-to-region start end))
      (switch-to-buffer buf)))
```

At this point, you will have a new buffer that contains the region you previously made. You can enable a major mode for that buffer and edit to your satisfaction--the changes you make are (like any good mirror should do) reflected in the original document.

Comment: This is a kind of more general solution.

Comment: Kinda the point. There's always more than one way. Mine is different. The pros and cons balance one way or another...

Comment: I'd recommend, today, 'org-edit-special (C-c ') mentioned in my reply below.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party but today the default (and recommended way without other hacks) is to switch to the dedicated elisp buffer for that "hunk" using 'org-edit-special which today is mapped to

> C-c- '

Hit the same to return to your org file editing.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch to a dedicated session with the right mode and auto-completion
simply with `C-c C-v z` when you are in a code block.

`C-c C-v z` or `C-c C-v`      `org-babel-switch-to-session-with-code`

Check the org-documentation 14.11 Key bindings and useful functions for more information.